# Play with data in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm starting a new Angular 2 project about Photos and Users.

On the server-side, The API is ready. I've created those classes already.

Now, I'm wondering...
In order to play around those objects on the client side, the best solution would be to rewrite those classes in typescript

```
let photo = new Photo(1, "http://url", "Some title");
```

or should I simply use standards objects

```
let photo = {
    id: 1,
    url: "http://...",
    title: "Some title"
}
```

?

The first solution requires to write twice the model (on the server, then on the client side).
The second solution is kind of old school, isn't it ?

Comment: You want interfaces. You define [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) for the data contracts between the server and client.

Comment: hi there. Hey! there are tons of ways you could create those entities based on your server side ones. I bet they ain't so different. Just to name a few> 1. You could copy paste them and remove the useless code
2. you could do point 1 with some sort of text editor macro
3. you could use your programming skills to make a program to write these classes for you based on the other code, if you're using C#, you could do it with reflection and a few foreach loops.

Comment: Thank you all for your advices. I think I'll rewrite a simpler version of my model on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you're going to recieve a JSON object from your API with your object's data. I've found casting that object immediately to a typed object is the best practice.  Using your example Photo object, lets imagine that is being returned from your Photo API endpoint.

```
{
    id: 1,
    url: "http://...",
    title: "Some title"
}
```

So I would suggest creating an interface for a photo object:

```
interface Photo {
  id: number,
  url: string,
  title: string
}
```

Keep in mind, interfaces are your chance to declare the language your application with use. For instance, if a 3rd party API returned a object key that was vague, say, lstPrc, you could redefined that in your interface to lastPrice!

Lastly, now that we have an interface, you can type and construct an object from the API's data:

// Assuming we're within the context of some sort of ajax callback

```
function (data) {
  const photo: Photo {
    id: data.id,
    url: data.url,
    title: data.title
  }

   // do cool things with our new photo object
}
```

The benefits of this newly typed object aren't always obvious right away without a history of working in strongly typed languages. You will, however, see a wealth of benefits going forward in this way. Extending and refactoring code becomes much easier and your IDE/text editor can provide very helpful code completion.